# msgbox loop closing

Tags: excel, vba, msgbox

I am doing coding for if cell 1 value is greater than cell 2 and 3 then message with abort and ignore button. But when I click on ignore, loop will not close pop is continue.

```
Sub op05_Press_Data()
Dim a As Worksheet
Set a = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TPS")

Dim result As VbMsgBoxResult

If a.Range("L15") <> "" Then

If a.Range("J18").Value > a.Range("J22") Then

result = MsgBox("Die R-L size more than Press Bolster R-L Size?", vbExclamation + vbYesNo) = vbNo
Exit Sub
End If

If a.Range("J18").Value > a.Range("J23") Then

MsgBox "Die R-L size more than Press Ram R-l Size", vbExclamation + vbYesNo = vbNo
Exit Sub
End If

If a.Range("K18").Value > a.Range("K22") Then

MsgBox "Die F-B size more than Press Bolster F-B Size", vbExclamation + vbYesNo = vbNo
Exit Sub
End If

If a.Range("K18").Value > a.Range("K23") Then

MsgBox "Die F-B size more than Press Ram F-B Size", vbExclamation + vbYesNo = vbNo
Exit Sub
End If
End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the script to continue if answers are No? This should do it:

```
Sub op05_Press_Data()
Dim a As Worksheet
Set a = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TPS")

If a.Range("L15") <> "" Then
  If a.Range("J18").Value > a.Range("J22") Then
    If MsgBox("Die R-L size more than Press Bolster R-L Size?", vbExclamation + vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub
  End If
  If a.Range("J18").Value > a.Range("J23") Then
    If MsgBox("Die R-L size more than Press Ram R-l Size", vbExclamation + vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub
  End If
  If a.Range("K18").Value > a.Range("K22") Then
    If MsgBox("Die F-B size more than Press Bolster F-B Size", vbExclamation + vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub
  End If
  If a.Range("K18").Value > a.Range("K23") Then
    If MsgBox("Die F-B size more than Press Ram F-B Size", vbExclamation + vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub
  End If
End If

End Sub
```